# How can I print out sensitive values from terraform state?

Tags: terraform

Goal: I want to print out a sensitive value of `foo_resource.name.sensitive_field`.

Originally I attempted to create an [output](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/output):

```
output "password" {
  value       = foo_resource.name.sensitive_field
}
```

and I got

```
 Error: Output refers to sensitive values
│ 
│   on main.tf line 186:
│  186: output "password" {
│ 
│ To reduce the risk of accidentally exporting sensitive data that was intended to be only internal, Terraform requires that any root module output containing sensitive data be
│ explicitly marked as sensitive, to confirm your intent.
│ 
│ If you do intend to export this data, annotate the output value as sensitive by adding the following argument:
│     sensitive = true
╵
```

so I added `sensitive = true` to it:

```
output "password" {
  value       = foo_resource.name.sensitive_field
  sensitive = true
}
```

and then when I run it again I got:

```
$ terraform output
password = <sensitive>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
terraform output -raw password
```

does the trick.

For more details see [the doc](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/output):

```
Note: When using the -json or -raw command-line flag, any sensitive values in Terraform state will be displayed in plain text. For more information, see Sensitive Data in State.
```

Comment: You don't even need `-raw`. You just have to specify the individual value name: `terraform output password`

Comment: Better and more efficient way is to use `nonsensitive()` function:
`output "my_password" {
  value = nonsensitive(azurerm_container_registry.my_container_registry.admin_password)
}`